# Mysql Explain Query show type “ALL”

Tags: mysql, explain

```
SELECT id FROM raod_busroute 
WHERE from_des LIKE '%adheriya khal%' AND to_des LIKE
'%abhayapuri%' GROUP BY from_des"
```

When I look at the result, I see it Reads the entire table—all rows and columns. I know this is  bad, but I don't know how to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `explain` result.

Comment: using like wildcard as `LIKE '%adheriya khal%' ` will never use index even if the column `from_des` is indexed. Hence the optimizer most likely to scan the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing a lookup with like with wildcards in the beginning of the string, mysql cannot use your indexes (if there are any). It needs to do a full table scan.